# Fedora 19 Pyclewn Cant Find GDB Version

Tags: python, vim, gdb, fedora

How do I get pyclewn to get my gdb version?

```
[mehoggan@localhost emulator]$ pyclewn
gdb  CRITICAL response to "show version":
***START***
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
~"GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora (7.6-32.fc19)\n"
~"Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.\n"
~"License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>\nThis is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.\nThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type \"show copying\"\nand \"show warranty\" for details.\n"
~"This GDB was configured as \"x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu\".\nFor bug reporting instructions, please see:\n"
~"<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.\n"
***END***


vim  CRITICAL 
Exception in pyclewn:

<class 'clewn.ClewnError'>
"cannot find the gdb version"
source line: "raise ClewnError('cannot find the gdb version')"
at /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/clewn/gdb.py:340

pyclewn aborting...


[mehoggan@localhost emulator]$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora (7.6-32.fc19)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem on my Red Hat box. I fixed it by going to the referenced file and line number : `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/clewn/gdb.py:340` and making the following fix:

Starting on line 328:

```
            version = ''.join(takewhile(lambda x: x.isdigit() or x == '.',
            version[1]))
```

and changing it to:

```
            version = ''.join(takewhile(lambda x: x.isdigit() or x == '.',
            version[1][1:]))
```

The problem is how it's dealing with the first '`(`' character in the version string:

```
[root@localhost ~ 03:52 PM] $ gdb -v

GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-42.el5)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
```

It's only using the first line of this output:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-42.el5)
```

By adding, the `[1:]` after `version[1]`, I'm telling the script to unconditionally skip the first character, which - on my machine, needs to happen. This probably isn't a long-term fix, but it got my pyclewn working =)

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem has been reported with Suse at

http://sourceforge.net/p/pyclewn/bugs/119/

This issue is fixed now in the pyclewn development branch and that
also fixes the problem with Fedora (7.6-32.fc19). So both problems
will be fixed in the next pyclewn release 1.11.

Both Fedora and Suse gdb distributions have a gdb header that is
non-conformant to GNU coding standards. Refer to the bug that has been
issued to Fedora bug tracker at:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1004949